# AWS Cloudformation: Attaching volume and mounting filesystem

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ebs

I am using the following Cloudformation resources to create and attach a volume to an EC2 instance:

```
  VOLData1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Volume
    DeletionPolicy: "Snapshot"
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: !GetAtt EC2ESDataNode1.AvailabilityZone
      Iops: 5000
      Size: 100
      VolumeType: "io1"
      Tags:
        - Key: "Name"
          Value: "es-data-1"


  VOLATTCHData1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment
    Properties:
      Device: "/dev/sdd"
      InstanceId: !Ref EC2ESDataNode1
      VolumeId: !Ref VOLData1
```

However, when I `ssh` into the instance:

```
pkara@ip-10-11-12-99:~$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0   18M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/930
loop1         7:1    0 88.2M  1 loop /snap/core/5897
nvme0n1     259:0    0    8G  0 disk 
└─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0    8G  0 part /
nvme1n1     259:2    0  100G  0 disk 
pkara@ip-10-11-12-99:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             31G     0   31G   0% /dev
tmpfs           6.2G  776K  6.2G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1  7.7G  3.1G  4.7G  40% /
tmpfs            31G     0   31G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            31G     0   31G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/930
/dev/loop1       89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/5897
tmpfs           6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/1001
```

Should I provision myself partition creation and the mounting of the new filesystem?
If so, what is the recommended way to go about it? (so that the mount point is not lost on each reboot)

Answer (score 1):

This is because after you attach the volume you need to mount it etc. AWS does not do this for you.  If you follow this page here it will help you out:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html

This details how to get the volume mounted, loosely you will need to create a mount-point and then mount the volume to it.  Once finished edit fstab to make sure it persists on re-creation.  You can do this all through EC2 Userdata but I would advise manually running through the steps first to make sure you're comfortable before automating.  Link below to documentation on Userdata:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html